# RegEx date pattern format validation not working as expected

Tags: regex

I'm trying to validate a date format input. The input is not the actual date but the `D` `M` `Y` input. And i **don't** want to validate the actual Date! just the formatting.

I want to evaluate any input done with double `D`, double `M`, double or quadruple `Y` with `-` or `_` dividers.

My current RegEx looks the following:
`^(?=.*[mM]{2})(?=.*[dD]{2})(?=.*[yY]{2,4})(?=.*[-_]{0,2}).*$`

However this evaluates true even if more than the expected characters are found. The Limiters `{2}` seem to have no effect.

For example: `mmddyyyymmmmmm` will evaluate true even there are multiple `m` in there. which i don't understand.

The expected result is that only combinations such as the following can test true:

```
dd-mm-yy
MM-DD_YYYY
yyyy_dd-MM
mmddyy
YYYYddMM
```

and not something like:

```
ddyyyyymmmmmmmmm
mmddyymm
```

Please help me to correct my RegEx.

Comment: That is rather a hard job for a regex, but `^(?!.*[mM]{2}.*[mM])(?!.*[Dd]{2}.*[Dd])(?!.*[yY]{4}.*[Yy])(?!.*(?:^|[^yY\n])[yY]{2}[^yY\n].*[yY])(?:(?:[mM]{2}|[dD]{2}|[yY]{2}(?:[yY]{2})?)(?:[_-](?!$))?){3}$` [looks to be doing](https://regex101.com/r/bJu2Lm/1) what you need. The `\n`s are there only since the test is performed against a multiline string.

Comment: This was def over my head to do myself. All i noticed is that it also evaluates `ddyyyy`, `yyyymm`, `yyyydd` true. I only need to evaluate single inputs so it's ok to do with regex, if i had to evaluate 1000s of values it be overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, it makes sense to match a string that can only match the string containing allowed blocks and then use some programming means to do the rest of the "counting" work (you just check how many `mm`, `dd`, or `yyyy` / `yy` there are).

If you have to use a regex, there are two approaches.

**Solution #1: Enumerating all alternatives**

It is the least comfortable, not dynamic/unscalable solution where you just collect all possible pattern inside a single group:

```
^(?:
  [dD]{2}[_-]?[mM]{2}[_-]?[yY]{2}(?:[yY]{2})? |
  [mM]{2}[_-]?[dD]{2}[_-]?[yY]{2}(?:[yY]{2})? |
  [mM]{2}[_-]?[yY]{2}(?:[yY]{2})?[_-]?[dD]{2} |
  [dD]{2}[_-]?[yY]{2}(?:[yY]{2})?[_-]?[mM]{2} |
  [yY]{2}(?:[yY]{2})?[_-]?[dD]{2}[_-]?[mM]{2} |
  [yY]{2}(?:[yY]{2})?[_-]?[mM]{2}[_-]?[dD]{2}
)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RM3PL4/2). `^` asserts the position in the start of the string, `(?:...|...)` non-capturing group with the alternatives and `$` asserts the end of string.

**Solution #2: Dynamic approach**

This approach means matching a string that only consists of three `D`, `M`, or `Y` blocks and restricting the pattern with positive lookaheads that will require the string to only contain a single occurrence of each block. The bottleneck and the problem is that the blocks are multi-character strings, and thus you need to use a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970) (or unwrap it, making the regex even more monstrous):

```
^
  (?=(?:(?![mM]{2}).)*[mM]{2}(?:(?![mM]{2}).)*$)
  (?=(?:(?![dD]{2}).)*[dD]{2}(?:(?![dD]{2}).)*$)
  (?=(?:(?![yY]{2}(?:[yY]{2})?).)*[yY]{2}(?:[yY]{2})?(?:(?![yY]{2}(?:[yY]{2})?).)*$)
  (?:
    (?:[mM]{2}|[dD]{2}|[yY]{2}(?:[yY]{2})?)
    (?:[_-](?!$))?
  ){3}
$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RM3PL4/1)

So, here, the `(?:[mM]{2}|[dD]{2}|[yY]{2}(?:[yY]{2})?)(?:[_-](?!$))?` parts repeats 3 times from start to end, so, the string can contain three occurrences of `d`, `y` or `m`, even if they are the same (`mmmmmm` will match, too). The lookaheads are all in the form of `(?=(?:(?!BLOCK).)*BLOCK(?:(?!BLOCK).)*$)` - matches only if there is any text but BLOCK, then a BLOCK and then any text but BLOCK till the end of the string.